pd.read_csv: error when "," comma is present in string column
I am reading in a csv file locally.The sep for the data is "|", so I specify pd.read_csv(repo, sep="|"). The data loads.
However, when I examine the data, the string column "movie_title" has put all of that row's data squished into the first column. This happens whenever a "," comma is present in "movie_title".
MRE
import pandas as pd

# when hosted in the cloud, repos can be public or private. this repo is public.
repo = "gs://minimum-reproduceable-2152532/item.csv"
cols = ["movie_id", "movie_title", "release_date", "video_release_date", "IMDB_url", "unknown", "Action", "Adventure", "Animation", "Childrens", "Comedy", "Crime", "Documentary", "Drama", "Fantasy", "Film-Noir", "Horror", "Musical", "Mystery", "Romance", "Sci-Fi", "Thriller", "War", "Western"]

df = pd.read_csv(repo, sep="|", names=cols, encoding="latin-1")

df.iloc[10:15, ::]

Is there any way to handle this in pandas, or will I have to break out excel and replace commas from there?

Please provide a [mre] of your data. It is difficult to help you without it.

MRE has been added.

Can you display a few lines of your csv?

@plotmaster473 this is not a MRE. What is gs://minimum-reproduceable-2152532/item.csv supposed to be? We can't access this URI. Please read How to make good reproducible pandas examples.

An MRE would include the item.csv content with the minimal lines and columns needed to reproduce the problem, such as the header (if any) and at least a couple lines of data such as one that reads correctly and one that causes the problem.  The code should be copy/paste/run without changes to reproduce the issue for readers, which means including the import statements and print statements to show the problem.

A bit confused as to what you are asking for. The above code runs from any jupyter notebook. If you are not set up with jupyter (not my target audience) then you will need to add a print statement to the final line.

So please let me know if, after running the above code, you are still running into problems.

People who don't use GCP cannot access Google Storage with the adress you gave. It should be:  https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/minimum-reproduceable-2152532/item.csv  . But then I get an access denied because my email  doesn't have the permissions to list objects on that storage. Why don't you just display few lines of the csv as asked by several people who kindly tried to help you ?

Looking at your dataframe, the only thing I see is that there is an additional " at the start of some cells in movie_id. Is it the only issue or there are other characters in these cells that don't show in the picture ?

Yes, I added the quotechars argument to read_csv. This successfully distributed the data across columns, but now there's that additional ", which I am having trouble getting rid of. Str.replace() did not work.

Ohhhhh wow. I was just brushing up on my regex and realized you can use strip() for cases other than whitespaces. haha... should be all set. Thanks very much.

Got it; had to add the "quotechar" parameter to pd.read_csv().
